# So i've come up with his code and i'm not sure how to continue with the delete function?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have to delete a drink from the database using the id the user enters.. so how should i continue? I'm not sure what to write inside the if condition?

```
class Drink{
private:
float cost;
char product_id[10];
char dname[30];
int numDrink;
public:    
void addDrink(char drinkname[],float price,char id[]); 
void delDrink(char drinkname[],char id[]);
//void updateItem();
//void searchItem();
};
Drink drinkBase[100];
void Drink::addDrink(char drinkname[],float price,char id[])
{

 strcpy(drinkBase[numDrink].dname,drinkname);
 strcpy(drinkBase[numDrink].product_id,id);
 drinkBase[numDrink].cost = price;
 cout<<"\nItem inserted successfully!"<<endl;
 numDrink++;
 }
 void Drink::delDrink(char drinkname[],char id[])
 {
 int i;
 for(int i=0;i<numDrink;i++){
    if((strcmp(drinkname,drinkBase[i].dname)==0)&& 
 (drinkBase[i].product_id=id))
    {

        cout<<"\nItem deleted successfully";
        return;
    }
 }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "how should I continue"? I don't see anything that needs continuing.  Why do you need to write more in the if condition?

Comment: For example you could write some unit tests now.

Comment: I'm new to c++, so excuse my ignorance.But isnt the program supposed to delete the whole index  from the database? Cant just print deleted successfully....?

Comment: You can't remove items from an array. You either mark the slot as deleted or move everything below it up one slot and write over it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your array size is fixed, you can "mark" it deleted by using a null name, and/or id. But then you run into issues with keeping track of the "last" drink via `numDrink`.

You could make it dynamically sized, but really you should use an STL [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) or [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). That way you can just do something like this:

```
for (auto it = drinks.begin(); it != drinks.end(); ++it) {
  if ((strcmp(drinkname,(*it).dname) == 0) && ((*it).product_id = id)) {
    drinks.erase(it);
    break;
  }
}
```

But be careful with iterators and loops. The code above works for removing a single item at a time. I recommend reading up on [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) if you are not familiar.

Comment: Thanks.But i dont know what is an STL list or vector. I'm looking for something rudimentary, for a beginner..? Could you please clarify how i'd use a null name to mark it deleted?

Comment: @LoneRanger "But i dont know what is an STL list or vector." Click the links Nick provided and find out. For a beginner they are much, much easier than writing all of the list management yourself.